# maximize profit based on rate of sales

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quadratics

Hope this kind of question is allowed. I am trying to figure out the max profit of an item based on how well it sells at different price points. I have the total number of views, percent of people who bought, number of sales, total revenue and of course the costs per item. I know that profit is equal to revenue minus cost, but how does the rate at which they are sold factor in? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you show us how far you've been tried? Maybe list out some formula/calculation?

Comment: Like I said, so far I know the basic way to figure out profit is P = revenue - cost , so I have P(x) = price(x) - cost/unit(x) - fee/shipping(x). But I don't want just the profit, I did some comparisons over 2 weeks at different price points and I want to figure out which is the most profitable based on the rate of views/sales. What's odd is the second highest price had most items sold at a lower rate and lowest price had bad views. So second highest seems best going through just the numbers, but I would like to figure out a way to calculate and continue to compare with real data.

Answer (score 0):

Revenue is price times sales.  The general idea is that a lower price generally means greater sales volume.  You need to model the relationship between cost and volume.  Often this is just a fixed cost plus some variable cost per unit made.  Then you need a model of sales versus price based on the data you have.  Then your profit can be expressed as a function of price which you can differentiate and set to zero to find the maximum.

Comment: The sales vs price bit is where I have the issue with, I have some idea of how the price impacts sales numbers (I have total sales, total views and percent conversion), but I'm not sure how to incorporate that rate into the profit model.  
Like I said, so far I know the basic way to figure out profit is P = revenue - cost , so I have P(x) = price(x) - cost/unit(x) - fee/shipping(x). I guess this seems overly simple. Any idea how I could account for the rate in this or even figure out sales vs price?